# React Jest Testing Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

I'm learning some testing with React and Jest, and I have some issues which I need some guidance on.

I have a logout method in my react component which looks like this:

```
  doLogout = async () => {
    const url = "/api/logout";

    let response;

    try {
      response = await fetch(url, { method: "post" });
    } catch (err) {
      alert("Failed to connect to server: " + err);
      return;
    }

    if (response.status !== 204) {
      alert("Error when connecting to server: status code " + response.status);
      return;
    }
```

my test report says I have some uncovered lines in this method, which I would like to cover:

```
headerbar.jsx |    78.95 |       75 |      100 |    78.95 |       21,22,26,27
```

Line 21: `alert("Failed to connect to server: " + err);`

Line 22: `return;`

Line 26: `alert("Error when connecting to server: status code " + response.status);`

Line 27: `return;`

All these lines are from the code above, I'm new to testing and I would like some guidance on these lines and how could I cover them in testing.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to test `Network error` and receiving a response that has a status other than `204`. Also, if you really want to test `alert`, you'd have to spy on it.

I, personally, use `axios-mock-adapter` for testing my API calls and with the use of it your remaining tests would look like this:

```
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
mock.onPost(url).networkError();

const alert = jest.spyOn(window, 'alert');

//mount your component and simulate your function

expect(alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Failed to connect to server: Network Error');
mock.restore();
alert.mockClear();
```

and

```
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

mock.onPost(url).reply(200, 'status code other than 204');

const alert = jest.spyOn(window, 'alert');

//mount your component and simulate your function

expect(alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Error when connecting to server: status code 200');
```